# UI Bootstrap datepicker says invalid date for ISO-8601 date string

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I receive the dates in ISO 8601 format <kbd>2011-11-14T14:48:00</kbd> from Web API as this is how the dates are serialized by default. On Client, I bind the date values with an input control and I am using [UI Bootstrap datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) for date controls. The binding happens well and I can see the date in any specified date format. But when I tab out from the control without making any changes, the model value becomes invalid. 
I don't think the date is invalid because if I delete a digit in the date value and retype the same and then tab out, the model value becomes valid.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}" ng-model="statusChangeDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" is-open="opened" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" ng-click="open($event, 'status')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

**Controller**

```
// This will come from a Web API call
$scope.statusChangeDate = '2011-11-14T14:48:00';
```

Comment: Insure that $scope.statusChangeDate is of Type Date.  

$scope.statusChangeDate = new Date('2011-11-14T14:48:00');

Comment: @Gray Thank you, that indeed worked, but I believe I need either a directive or filter to parse all ISO date strings to date objects as the Web API will always serialize in ISO strings

Comment: Not knowing exactly what you are doing, hard to give an exact answer on how to deal with that.  However, a common practice in our code is to modify incoming data after it is loaded successfully.  Iterate over the results, and convert the strings into Dates.

Comment: Yes and this iteration is what I think needs to be generalize. There could be multiple places in our application, where we receive date strings from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insure that $scope.statusChangeDate is of Type Date. $scope.statusChangeDate = new Date('2011-11-14T14:48:00');

Comment: I happen to find that calling new Date('2011-11-14T14:48:00') will localize the the date by adding/subtracting the time zone of the browser resulting a change in the original date.

Answer (score 3):

For automatic string to date transforming I created simple attribute directive:

(lodash or underscore required, or good luck with replacing to native JS functions)

```
.directive('transformStringToDate', function () {
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    var ngModel = attr.ngModel;
    var value = _.propertyOf(scope)(ngModel);
    if (!_.isUndefined(value)) {
      if (_.isString(value)) {
        var lastIndexOfDot = _.lastIndexOf(ngModel, '.');
        if (lastIndexOfDot < 0) {
          scope[ngModel] = new Date(value);
        } else {
          var parentObject = _.propertyOf(scope)(ngModel.substr(0, lastIndexOfDot));
          parentObject[ngModel.substr(lastIndexOfDot + 1)] = new Date(value);
        }
      } else if(_.isDate(value)) {
        console.log("No need to transform date", value, ngModel);
      }
    }
  }
}
})
```

Usage in HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">Bla bla:</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             uib-datepicker-popup="{{'MMM dd, yyyy'}}"
             ng-model="someObject.anotherObject.myDate"
             transform-string-to-date
             is-open="myDatePopup"
             ng-required="true"
             close-text="Close"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="myDatePopup = true">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
         </button>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zTp5wFCxImtFNJB9CaRb?p=preview